# how can i define E, a set of linear function from $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in a set notation form?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My attempt is : 
$E = \{f\ |\ f(x) = ax+b, a,b\in \mathbb{R};\ x\in A\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a good attempt, but here's a slightly more rigorous one:
$$E = \lbrace f : A \to \mathbb{R} \mid \exists a, b \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in A, \; f(x) = ax + b \rbrace,$$
or indeed
$$E = \lbrace f : A \to \mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$} \rbrace.$$
You are allowed to use words!

Comment: okey, thank you so much...